# dtd file doesn't affect xml file

Tags: xml, dtd

I've got simple xml document. But I need to use DTD file too. 
But when I add it or don't add - it changes nothing. File doesn't affect my xml page.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet  type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"?>
<!DOCTYPE software SYSTEM "software.dtd">
<software>
<application>
    <suite>
        <office>
            <app>
                <title>Microsoft Office</title>
                <developer>Microsoft</developer>
                <os>Microsoft Windows</os>
                <license>Trialware</license>
            </app>
            <app>
                <title>iWork</title>
                <developer>Apple</developer>
                <os>Mac OS</os>
                <license>Proprietary</license>
            </app>
            <app>
                <title>Open Office</title>
                <developer>StarOffice,OpenOffice.org,Apache OpenOffice</developer>
                <os>Linux, Mac OS, Microsoft Windows</os>
                <license>LGPL,Apache License</license>
            </app>
        </office>
    </suite>
</application>
```

And here my .dtd file

```
<!DOCTYPE software
[
<!ELEMENT software(application)>
<!ELEMENT application(suite)>
<!ELEMENT suite(office)>
<!ELEMENT office(app)>
<!ELEMENT app(title,developer,os,license)>
<!ELEMENT title(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT developer(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT os(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT license(#PCDATA)>
] 
>
```

When I change it to sth like this - xml page still shows everything normal.

```
<!DOCTYPE software
[
<!ELEMENT look ANY>
] 
>
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Is the DTD file located at the same path as your XML file?

Comment: You'll need to explain that a little more: "catalog" is not a standard file system term, so presumably you're using some XML program.  As Michael Key noted, it's impossible to answer this question without knowing which program that is, because XML files don't normally just validate themselves simply because you gave them a DTD; usually you have to tell your program to do validation somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Whether an XML parser performs validation or not depends on how you invoke it. It's quite possible (and common) to have a DTD and still not to do validation. You need to indicate what parser you are using and how you are invoking it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use DTD to limit elements that are displayed when you view your XML file in a browser, that isn't what DTD is for and it isn't going to work. DTD is for basic validation of a document.

You can use XML stylesheets or (preferrably) XSLT to transform the XML for display purposes.